# MKMapView in satellite mode displays black screen while zooming

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

[image]

This problem occurs only in satellite map. Is there a fix to avoid displaying this black screen?

Note: Apple Map application not displaying this black screen in device But MKMapView displaying this black screen.

Comment: Have you got any solution for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Set zoomlevel of **mapView** to maximum **zoom level 18** as `MKMapView` didn't have predefine zoomlevel set so we have to set it manually using `MKCoordinateSpan`

About zoomlevel you will get help by this link http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/mkmapview-and-zoom-levels-a-visual-guide/

Comment: I have implemented this method and I am zooming the map initially with zoom level 17. The actual problem is when I pinch zoom the map to an extent, map displays this black screen as an indication of end of map zooming. But i need the map to behave like android where it displays blur map displaying last updated location.

Comment: Well there is a bit of difference between ios and android you can do 1 thing like on delegate method of MKMapView when you zoom the map check there if it exceed to zoomlevel 17 or 18 stop it right there or dont zoom it

Comment: Yes I have implemented that logic too. When I retrieve the zoom level in method 'regionWillChangeAnimated' it returns the last zoom level. In case of 'regionDidChangeAnimated' method it returns the updated zoom level but the map is already zoomed and it displays the black screen.

Comment: so do it before your required level like on 17 or 16